# Drag-n-Drop in GWT 2.3

Tags: java, gwt, drag-and-drop, smartgwt

I have two grids - one is TreeGrid and other one is Simple Grid. How do i implement the Drag-n-Drop in that as GWT 2.3 doesn't provide Drag-n-Drop feature in Grids. And simultaneously when drop event is fired i need to attach button with the elements of the grid. So is there any solution that can meet my requirements in GWT 2.3 ??

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [gwt-dnd](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-dnd/) it's an excellent drag'n'drop library. I'm using it intensively in a project and it works very well. However I'm not sure whether it supports TreeGrid and SimpleGrid.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the dnd plugin of gwtquery 
 http://code.google.com/p/gwtquery-plugins/wiki/DragAndDropPluginForGWTDeveloppers

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using SmartGWT you can use their own drag and drop API - see the showcase for examples:  http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#effects_dd_tree_move_drag_nodes